# XCode with boost "Semantic Issue - undeclared identifier va_start"

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, boost

```
C++locale.h
->Semantic Issue
-->Use of undeclared identifier 'va_start'
->Semantic Issue
-->Use of undeclared identifier 'va_end'
```

First time using boost, downloaded it using ports and created a command line project in XCode.
Header Search Path: /usr/include/**

There is nothing in the code yet, just the main function that comes with the default proj.

Just don't know what to do, never expected this to happen.

EDIT1:

First occurrence:

```
#ifndef _GLIBCXX_CSTDARG
#define _GLIBCXX_CSTDARG 1

#pragma GCC system_header

#include <bits/c++config.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

// Adhere to section 17.4.1.2 clause 5 of ISO 14882:1998
#ifndef va_end
#define va_end(ap) va_end (ap)
#endif

_GLIBCXX_BEGIN_NAMESPACE(std)

  using ::va_list;

_GLIBCXX_END_NAMESPACE

#endif
```

It's a file without extension in \usr\include\c++\4.2.1 and i just realized that this file has nothing to do with boost, there is something nasty happening here.

EDIT2: After fixing the include dir to /opt/local/include/** new errors appeared:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/c++/v1/type_traits:214:46:
Use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
```

There are other errors, all related to these files in the folder sr/lib/c++/v1/ why is that? These file seems to be some core functionality, they can't be broke.

Here is a pic of the errors, maybe ou guys see something
[image: Errors]

EDIT3: Changing the compiler from Apple LLVM to GCC LLVM reduces the errors to only one:
"vspintf is not a member of 'std'" in c++locale.h. Ok, now I'm completely lost.

Comment: Do any errors occur when you actually compile/build?  Or is it just a warning from the Xcode IDE?

Comment: First, are you building in the Xcode GUI, via xcodebuild, or using the command line toolchain? Do you have multiple Xcode versions? Have you changed Xcode versions since installing MacPorts? (I asked the last because I had exactly that problem—boost was built against the 10.6 SDK, and when I updated Xcode I no longer had a 10.6 SDK, and in command-line builds that leads to bizarre errors that look just like yours.)

Comment: Also, if you're using clang rather than gcc, make sure you're not mixing libc++ and libstdc++.

Comment: It's an error, it wont finishes the build. Compiling with Xcode IDE.
I've just installed macpors to install boost, it's the same xcode since them.
I don't know what I'm using, I think it's the default compiler(LLVM)

Comment: Just created another fresh XCode command line tool app. There is no errors at all when building the Hello World, but just adding the Header Search Path breaks the compilation with the above stated error, there is no reference to boost in my code yet, just added the search path.

Comment: Why are you using `/opt/local/include/**` instead of just `/opt/local/include`, by the way? It's really much better to `#include <boost/foo.hpp>` instead of `#include <foo.hpp>`; even if you've got lots of pre-existing code that for some reason can't be fixed, it's better to add `/opt/local/include/boost` instead of `/opt/local/include/**`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you're may not be `#include`ing the right headers.

For example, if you don't `#include <cstddef>`, you can't use `std::nullptr_t`; attempting to do so will give you:

```
Semantic issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'. Did you mean 'nullptr'?
```

Often, pulling in one header happens to implicitly pull in various other headers, so things work even when they shouldn't. libstdc++ does this a lot more than libc++, and the former is the default library for llvm-g++ ("GCC LLVM"), the latter for clang ("Apple LLVM"), which means a lot of errors will seem to go away when you switch to "GCC LLVM" (or just stick with "Apple LLVM" and switch your library), but your code is still wrong.

Another possibility is that you're trying to compile C++11 in C++03 mode. For example, when you `#include <cstddef>` in C++03 mode, it shouldn't define `nullptr_t`. It might do so anyway—and it might do so with llvm-g++ and/or libstdc++, but not with clang and/or libc++. But your code (or, in this case, your project) is still wrong and should be fixed.

If you can show us the actual (stripped-down) code that generates these errors, and tell us exactly what settings you changed from the default "Command Line Tool, C++" project you created in Xcode (assuming that's what you created), it should be possible to be more specific.

To get a minimal program working with boost, assuming you've got Xcode, MacPorts, and MacPorts boost installed properly, all you have to do is this:

- Create a new Command Line Tool, C++.
- Click on the project, then under Search Paths, go to Header Search Paths, and edit it to add `/opt/local/include`.
- Modify `main.cpp` to look like the following:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    boost::uuids::uuid u1 = {
        0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78,
        0x90, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef,
        0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78,
        0x90, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef };
    boost::uuids::uuid u2 = {
        0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78,
        0x90, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef,
        0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78,
        0x90, 0xab, 0xcd, 0xef };
    std::cout << (u1 == u2) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I picked boost::uuid because it's a dead-simple library, but the same should work for compiling any part of boost.

Some parts of boost also require you to link in a library. For that, you'll also need to add `/opt/local/lib` to Library Search Paths before you can use most of the usual techniques for adding libraries to a project.

Note that if you're up to date, you can make this even shorter, because with Xcode 4.5, the defaults will be Apple LLVM Compiler 4.1, GNU++11 dialect, and libc++ with C++11 support library. But I made sure my code was C++03-compatible so it works with the defaults in almost any version of Xcode (I tested with 3.2), since you never told us what version you were using.

Comment: I've re-downloaded boost with homebrew, it seems homebrew put boost in /usr/local/include, any problem? Xcode and ML are updating right now, after they update I'll create a brand new project, add boost to the header search path and upload it so you can take a look.

Comment: Should be no problem, especially since that's what I'm using myself; just use `/usr/local` in place of `/opt/local` any place it appears above. (Unless you have both Homebrew and MacPorts installed, which is generally a bad idea. If you have problems, you may want to temporarily hide MacPorts by, e.g., `sudo mv /opt/local /opt/local-bak`.)

Comment: This does not work with xcode 5.1 =( still the same errors, any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, I've installed Boost with homebrew and when I add the 'Header Search Path' (/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.54.0/include with the recursive option) in XCode the build throw those errors.

To fix it I changed the recursive option to non-recursive on the 'Header Search Path' and it worked.

Comment: Changing recursive to non-recursive solved my issue on Mavericks

Comment: Yes, the recursive to non-recursive was my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and solved it. In XCode on osx mavericks had to add /opt/local/libs/ to the library search path (non-recursive). I then added /opt/local/include/ to the header search path (also non-recursive).

Answer (score 2):

You need to `#include <stdarg.h>` in order to use the `va_start` macros et al.  If those errors are happening in a header file, then that header file should include `<stdarg.h>`; if it doesn't, you can work around it by including it yourself *before* you include the problematic header (but you should also report the issue to the library developers, if possible).

Comment: I've edited the question with the file were the occurrence first happens, it looks like it already has stdarg.h included

Answer (score 1):

From the latest comment, I think I know the problem.

> Header Search Path: /usr/include/**
>
> Just created another fresh XCode command line tool app. There is no errors at all when building the Hello World, but just adding the Header Search Path breaks the compilation with the above stated error, there is no reference to boost in my code yet, just added the search path.

Where did you get the search path `/usr/include/**`?

MacPorts installs everything to `/opt/local`, not `/usr`, so you want `/opt/local/include` (or `/opt/local/include/**` or `/opt/local/include/boost`); adding `/usr/include/**` isn't going to help at all with Boost.

However, it *may* break your code even before you get to Boost.

What's in `/usr/include` is Xcode's Command Line Tools. If you don't have these, you've got an incomplete and unusable set of headers; if you do, you've got a set of headers that conflicts with SDK-based builds.

The answer is to not add `/usr/include/**` to your search path.

Or, if you really need to add it (but really, you don't), change the Base SDK to "Current OS X" instead of "Latest OS X", which means you'll be getting your default headers out of `/usr/include` instead of, e.g., `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk/usr/include`, and of course adding a path that's already there won't lead to any conflicts.

Comment: The situation changed, I've bee misguided to put what macports downloaded and installed in /usr by a page which I could not found right now. But now I have new erros, all of them "Semantic", I'll update the question with the proper error and file.

Comment: If you could share a XCode Project working with boost, I would be so glad.

Comment: Well, my boost is installed by Homebrew rather than MacPorts, so you'd have to edit Header Search Paths from `/usr/local/include` to `/opt/local/include`. And, since that's the only thing I changed from the defaults, you can just as easily start with a default.

Comment: See my other answer for step by step instructions.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, and got all these errors when using Boost in my Xcode project. After trial and error I found that the Header and Library paths should be non-recursive. Once I did that, it all compiled without errors.

Comment: I installed Boost with the Boost.Build package. It installs into /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include/boost by default. On the advice of this answer, I added /usr/local/include/boost to my header search path, instead of /usr/local/include, and most of the errors went away. The remaining error is probably unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed it. After trying installs with homebrew, macports and manually, it was hard to find everything that needed changing in the backend of Xcode, which I admit to still finding a little confusing at times.
So Header search paths still contained the homebrew cellar as part of the long pathname, so I changed this bit /usr/include
User Header Path I had as /usr/local/lib according to some instructions I'd found searching for a solution. I've now changed it to /usr/local/lib

After these changes, my errors have finally disappeared! Fingers crossed I've got it right now