# boost compile error Mac OS X 10.7.4

Tags: c++, macos, boost

I want to use boost on my Mac.

Mac OS X 10.7.4
Xcode 4.5

I installed boost by homebrew.

```
brew install boost
```

Boost version is 1.49.0.
And I set up my Xcode project.

Add Header search path.

```
/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.49.0/include
```

Add libraries

```
libboost * .dylib
```

When I compile my project, I have many errors. Clang LLVM 1.0 Error.
( I want to upload an image, but I can't upload becase I don't have more than 10 reputation. )

```
use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
too few template arguments for class template '__is_function'
use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
field has incomplete type 'std::exception_ptr'
expected ';' at end of declaration list
no member named 'memcpy' in namespace 'std::__1'; did you mean 'memcpy'?
no member named 'memcpy' in namespace 'std::__1'; did you mean 'memcpy'?
expected ';' at end of declaration list
expected ';' at end of declaration list
C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
'operator==' cannot be the name of a variable or data member
use of undeclared identifier 'nullptr_t'; did you mean 'nullptr'?
expected ';' at end of declaration
expected unqualified-id
expected ';' at end of declaration list
unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
unknown type name 'nullptr_t'
qualified reference to 'shared_ptr' is a constructor name rather than a type wherever a constructor can be declared
too many errors emitted, stopping now
```

I checked this question.

[XCode with boost "Semantic Issue - undeclared identifier va_start"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573271/xcode-with-boost-semantic-issue-undeclared-identifier-va-start)

But I couldn't find answers.
Please let me know if there is a solution.

The header file using boost is like this.

**GLTexture.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __GL_TEXTURE_HPP__
#define __GL_TEXTURE_HPP__

// Standard libraries.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable:4819)
#endif

// Smart pointers.
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/scoped_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>

// Foreach macros.
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

// Regular expression.
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

// Image I/O.
#define png_infopp_NULL (png_infopp)NULL
#define int_p_NULL (int*)NULL
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png_io.hpp>

// File operations,
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

// Linear algebra,
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

// String functions.
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

// Serialization
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma warning (pop)
#endif

// OpenGL and OpenGL Utility Toolkit
#ifdef _WIN32

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GLUT.h>

#elif defined __APPLE__

#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>


#endif

#include "TextureManager.hpp"
#include <time.h>

class TextureManager;

using namespace std;


/// function to convert RGB image to RGBA image.
/// Filling its alpha channel with 255.
/// This function is called from boost::gil::copy_and_convert_pixels()
namespace boost { 
    namespace gil {
        template <> void color_convert<rgb8_pixel_t,rgba8_pixel_t>(const rgb8_pixel_t& src,rgba8_pixel_t& dst);
    }
}


class GLTexture
{
public:

    //Destructor
    ~GLTexture();

    //Return instance of GLTexture
    static boost::shared_ptr<GLTexture> getInstance(const std::string& filename, bool _isVolatile = true);

    //Load image file and generate texture
    bool LoadFromFile(boost::shared_ptr<GLTexture> texture);

    //Bind texture when the texture exists. If the texture doesn't exist, this method generates a texture.
    static void bindTexture(boost::shared_ptr<GLTexture> texture);

    //Setter of texFileName
    void setTextureFile(const std::string filename);
    //Setter of volatile Flag
    void setIsVolatile(bool _isVolatile);  

    //Getter of texture ID
    inline const GLuint& getTextureID(void)const{
        return this->texture;
    };

    //Overload of operator to sort list
    friend bool operator <(const boost::shared_ptr<GLTexture>& texture1, const boost::shared_ptr<GLTexture>& texture2);
    friend std::ostream& operator <<(ostream& os, const boost::shared_ptr<GLTexture>& texture);




public:
    GLuint texture;             //texture id
    std::string texFileName;    //image file path
    int width;                  //width of image
    int height;                 //height of image
    clock_t start, end;         //start is the timing of bindTexture, end is the timing of delete, these are used to sort list.
    bool isVolatile;            //the flag whether this texture is volatile or not. true is volatile, and false is not volatile. To keep texture, this is false.
    bool isRead;                //the flag whether this texture already exists in texturelist. true means "exists", false means "not exists".

    boost::shared_ptr<boost::gil::rgba8_image_t> pixelData_ptr;                     //smart pointer to contain pixelData
    boost::shared_ptr<boost::gil::rgba8_image_t::const_view_t> viewwithAlpha_ptr;   //smart pointer to contain viewData




private:
    //Forbid copy constructor
    GLTexture();
    GLTexture(const std::string& imageFilePath, bool _isVolatile = false);
    GLTexture(const GLTexture& glTexture);
    GLTexture& operator = (const GLTexture& glTexture);

    //load image from SSD
    bool LoadImage(const std::string& filename);




};

#endif
```

**TextureManager.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#ifndef __TEXTURE_MANAGER_HPP__
#define __TEXTURE_MANAGER_HPP__

// Standard libraries.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma warning (push)
#pragma warning (disable:4819)
#endif

// Smart pointers.
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>

#include <boost/shared_array.hpp>

// Foreach macros.
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

// Regular expression.
#include <boost/regex.hpp>

// Image I/O.
#define png_infopp_NULL (png_infopp)NULL
#define int_p_NULL (int*)NULL
#include <boost/gil/gil_all.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/jpeg_io.hpp>
#include <boost/gil/extension/io/png_io.hpp>

// File operations,
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

// Linear algebra,
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/matrix.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

// String functions.
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

// Serialization
#include <boost/serialization/serialization.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/version.hpp>

#ifdef _WIN32
#pragma warning (pop)
#endif

// OpenGL and OpenGL Utility Toolkit
#ifdef _WIN32

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/GLUT.h>

#elif defined __APPLE__

#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>


#endif

#include "GLTexture.hpp"


class GLTexture;

class TextureManager
{
public:
    TextureManager(void);
    ~TextureManager(void);

    //Generate Texture
    static void genTexture(boost::shared_ptr<GLTexture> texture);


    static void setTexture(const boost::shared_ptr<GLTexture> texture);

    static void deleteTexture();
    static bool checkList(const std::string& filename);


private:

    //Forbid copy constructor
    TextureManager(const TextureManager& texManager);
    TextureManager& operator = (const TextureManager& texManager);  

};

#endif
```

Comment: Have you tried to change your compiler from Apple LLVM to GCC LLVM?

Comment: Could you show the relevant code that produces the errors?

Comment: @Ninten I tried to change compiler to GCC LLVM, but I had same errors.

Comment: @MortenKristensen OK, I'm using boost in my OpenGL project.

Comment: @maasaamiichii I'm having the same error on my machine with a different project. Hopefully someone knows what the problem is.

Answer (score 15):

Did you use recursive search path for the headers? If so change it to non-recursive. That might solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had similary problem!I soved the problem that:
Xcode->Buid Setting->C++ language Dialect(GNU++11)
                   ->C++Standard Library(libc++(LLVM C++ with C++ 11)

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Xcode 7.2 but changing the C++ Language settings to match yours (and other combinations too) doesn't stop the errors.

Comment: @MichaelIV No, sorry. I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add

```
#include <cstring>
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy