# Can't build iOS project with boost: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, boost

I append Boost to my iOS project via brew package manager:

```
brew install boost
```

Then add header path to project settings:

```
/usr/local/**
```

And now project doesn't builds with error:

```
ld: file not found: ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ios-hgivqqzmkrkxlvdazbhavxnxtxod/Build/Intermediates/ios.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/ios.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/TLRPCmessages_searchGifs.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

`DerivedData/.../x86_64` folder doesn't contains any `*.o` files (only `.d`, `.dia` and `.dat`), why it talks only about one?

---

Also I tried change header path to non-recursive: `/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.60.0_1/include`, and 
build errors became as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573271/xcode-with-boost-semantic-issue-undeclared-identifier-va-start#12574479)

But I can't understand answers - `#include <cstddef>` already exists inside boost, compiler is Apple LLVM:

[image: Errors]

How can I fix this bugs?

Comment: I don't see how your linker error has anything to do with boost.  Is the source file generated from an IDL file of some sort?

Comment: Errors from screenshot are inside boost files, at least some of them.
Files that needs boost are not my own files, they was downloaded from [Telegram iOS sample](https://github.com/peter-iakovlev/Telegram) and contains large number of rows like `#include <map>` or `std::tr1::unordered_map`. What additional info can I give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem manually but did not remember how. Anyway my solution was bad because of application size enlarged over 100 Mbytes!

[CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) helped me, `boost` pod already exists .

Just add row to `Podfile`:

```
pod 'boost'
```

and run `pod install` in project directory. With this pod project was built without errors and application size was not so huge.